# Why client cannot parse the http packet built and sent by libnet?

Tags: c, linux, http, libnet

I build a http packet by using libnet build functions, and send it by libnet_write. I see the packet is sent successfully via wireshark, the tcp and ip header are all right. But client cannot parse my packet. For example, the client doesn't load the html when I send "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" packet; the client doesn't jump to the redirect site when I send "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily" packet. etc..

Comment: Just because it is sent, doesn't mean the payload isn't garbage, right?  Perhaps including how you're building the packet would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The payload, that is http data, is like this:
"HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n"
"Location: http://www.example.com\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
"Content-Length: 0\r\n"
"Connection: close\r\n"
"\r\n"
I don't know what is wrong about it? @FiddlingBits

Answer (score 0):

You provide no code in your question, and no example of the packet you construct, but HTTP runs over TCP, and you mention writing only a single packet. This cannot work. Establishing a TCP connection requires writing a SYN packet, reading the SYN/ACK response, and writing a final ACK.

Only after this 3-packet exchange can a TCP packet with data be sent.

Also, its not at all clear why you are trying to do this. If you want data to be received by an HTTP server, you should construct and send it with the normal socket APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My system is deployed at bypass of gateway, which can monitor internal traffic, if a client attempts to request a certain site, I will send RST to server and a redirect packet to client. For example, if client tries to access to google.com, I need redirect it to facebook.com. I capture packet using libpcap, build and send new packet via libnet. The information of building packet is obtained from the last client  HTTP GET request packet. @Sam Roberts

Comment: And now, I can interrupt the connection to server, however, using wireshark, I can see that client doesn't send new request to new site after receiving 302 redirect packet . I feel that client's browser doesn't parse the http packet built by libnet. @Sam Roberts